# perl networking tutorial

Tags: perl, web-applications

So far I've been using wget and curl to do screen scraping. Now I would like to switch to perl. What's a good tutorial that will cover basic web programming in perl (preferably without restating the basics)? I'm talking about basic things like getting and parsing pages, submitting forms, proxies, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools you will need besides Perl:

1. **HTTP Live Headers** (Firefox extension) or eqv. to reverse engineer Javascript requests to primitive GET / POST so you can mimic that with Mechanize or LWP, etc.
2. As already mentioned by other posters, a good headless-browser is `WWW::Mechanize` module.
3. I would suggest spending some time learning `HTML::TreeBuilder` & especially `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` and `HTML::Query`. the last two will become very handy when you will want to get actual data from HTML documents.
4. `HTML::TableExtract` is also a nice module to extract data from HTML tables when needed.

basically, using all of the above will give you the ability to crawl most sites.

Have fun crawling (-:

Comment: Web::Query supports more complicated selectors than HTML::Query because it does not implement this on its own, but delegates this part to the excellent feature-complete HTML::Selector::XPath.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [WWW-Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) in the past to achieve the basic web crawling functionality, including form submission and the like.

There are some pretty good [examples](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Examples.pod).

Answer (score 1):

These should pretty much cover everything you're looking for:

http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html

http://lwp.interglacial.com/

http://www.perl.com/pub/2003/01/22/mechanize.html

http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linux/ldp/LDP/LGNET/108/oregan2.html